# Create splash page on zend framework site

Tags: zend-framework

How would i go about creating an html splash page that would be the first page when someone goes to the site. The site is built on zend framework.

I guess it doesn't have to be html, could be php.

I have tried updating the htaccess file with DirectoryIndex index.html

Adding redirect code, (broke site)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I found a way through htaccess:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$

RewriteRule (.*) main.html [L,QSA]

Answer (score 1):

Just create a IndexController, with an index action and an index view

Or use a router to direct / to a particular controller/view

Comment: I am familiar with the indexController, but not the router. What would I do in the router, where do i find it?

Comment: Create a route in your bootstrap see http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html